# bootstrap progress bar with an icon as a pointer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to create this dynamic progress bar to display certain values, the only problem that I'm having is that the icon is not precise, it overflows on the right as well as on the left. the pic is clear, the problem is in the icon within the red circle. thanks for the help in advance.

[This is a screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3e4d.png)

this is the HTML part :

```
enter code here
 <div class="progress p-0 m-0" style="background-color: #696969; height: 30px; width :100%">
           <div id="pointerRealise" class="progress"  style="background-color: #00ff01; height: 30px; ">
            <div id="pointerCible" class="bar-step" style="left: 100%">

             <div class="fa-3x">
              <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down" data-fa-transform="grow-40"></i>
<span class="fa-layers-text fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8 up-2" style="font-weight:1000">
<?php // echo number_format($cibEnPRct*100 ,2) ."%";
                    echo str_replace(",","",$ciblAff);
            ?>
</span>
```

This is the css part :

```
  <style type="text/css">
 .bar-step {
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-100px;
  z-index:1;}
.ruler {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
height: 24px;
}
.ruler .cm,
.ruler .mm {
position: absolute;
border-left: 1px solid #555;
height: 24px;
width: 10%;
}
.ruler .cm:after {
position: absolute;
bottom: -25px;
font: 17px/0.1 sans-serif;
}
.ruler .mm {
height: 15px;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(5) {
height: 20px;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(1) {
left: 0%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(1):after {
content: "0";
left: -10%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(2) {
left: 10%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(2):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.1;  ?>";
left: -35%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(3) {
left: 20%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(3):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.2;  ?>"; left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(4) {
left: 30%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(4):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.3;  ?>"; left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(5) {
left: 40%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(5):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.4;  ?>"; left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(6) {
left: 50%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(6):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.5;  ?>"; left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(7) {
left: 60%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(7):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.6;  ?>";left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(8) {
left: 70%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(8):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.7;  ?>";left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(9) {
left: 80%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(9):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.8;  ?>";left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(10) {
left: 90%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(10):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj*0.9;  ?>";left: -25%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(11) {
left: 100%;
}
.ruler .cm:nth-of-type(11):after {
content: "<?php echo $obj;  ?>";left: -25%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(1) {
left: 10%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(2) {
left: 20%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(3) {
left: 30%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(4) {
left: 40%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(5) {
left: 50%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(6) {
left: 60%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(7) {
left: 70%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(8) {
left: 80%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(9) {
left: 90%;
}
.ruler .mm:nth-of-type(10) {
left: 100%;
}
</style>
```

this is the JS where i reposition the icon :

```
<script>
document.getElementById("pointerRealise").style.width = <?php echo json_encode(number_format($realEnPrct*100 ,2) ."%"); ?>;
document.getElementById("pointerCible").style.left = <?php echo json_encode(number_format($cibEnPRct*100 ,2) ."%"); ?>;
</script>
```